# VBA excel to delete cell contents in a range A3:A999 on a cover sheet if it equals Cell D1 value

Tags: excel, vba

VBA excel to delete cell contents in a range A3:A999 on a cover sheet if it equals the Cell D1 value that i put in from another piece of code. this is probably simple but it is confusing me at the minute.

Answer (score 0):

```
If myWorksheet.Range("D1") = myValue then myWorksheet.Range("A3:A999").ClearContents
```

To explain: myWorksheet = a worksheet variable. Its always a good idea to express what sheet you're working on. This is done with the Set command e.g. Set myWorksheet = Sheets("Sheet 1")
.ClearContents clears any values in the parent range but leaves any formatting. Use .Clear instead to clear the cells to their empty defualt state.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to remove the cell content from the cells in the range A3:A999 if the cell content is equal to the value in cell D1. For this you will need a loop going through each cell separately, comparing cell content and clearing cell contents if necessary.

```
For X = 3 To 999
    If Range("A" & X).Value = Range("D1").Value Then
        Range("A" & X).Clear
Next X
```

This will clear the cell contents if the condition is met (i.e the cells AX and D1 have same content where X is the integer used for the iteration). Note that for this to work you need to have the correct worksheet active (otherwise precede the ranges with the name of the worksheet and a dot: `worksheetName.`)